# Generating random numbers with given probabilities in C++

Tags: c++, random

How do I generate a random number between 0 and 100 in C++ using `rand()` function when the probability of getting 0 is 10%, 1 is 7% and the probability of getting rest of the number is equal?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and visit the [help]. As-is this is too broad for SO format.

Comment: This seems to be more of a math question that a programming one.

Comment: Apparently, your approach is to beg other people to work it out.   More generally, work out an algorithm (e.g. describe a sequence of steps on paper that would achieve your intended effect), translate that description into code.    Generally speaking, this site is about helping with specific problems you have encountered in trying to do it yourself (i.e. you present a [mcve], describe what results you get and how they differ from what you expect, so people can help you help yourself).  You haven't done that, so your question will probably be marked as off-topic.

Comment: 1). Work out what the *quantile* function q(p) is for your distribution. 2) Draw a uniform random number `p` in the range [0, 1). 3) The random number you want is q(p).

Answer (score 3):

The `rand()` function is probably the wrong tool to do the job here. C++ since C++11 has new tools for (pseudo-)random number generation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random Among these tools is the concept of a [RandomNumberDistribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomNumberDistribution), and one of those distributions is provided by [std::discrete_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution). std::discrete_distribution lets you define the weights of numbers in a distribution, so that different numbers can have different, pre-defined probabilities.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <random>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    std::random_device r;
    std::default_random_engine e1(r());
    // Distribution that defines different weights (17, 10, etc.) for numbers.
    std::discrete_distribution<int> discrete_dist({17, 10, 5, 3, 1});

    // The map keeps track of number of occurences for each value.
    std::map<int, int> histogram;
    for (int n = 0; n < 100; ++n) {
        ++histogram[std::round(discrete_dist(e1))];
    }
    std::cout << "Distribution:\n";
    for (auto p : histogram) {
        std::cout << p.first << ' ' << p.second << '\n';
    }
}
```

The output could be something like:

```
Distribution:
0 51
1 23
2 13
3 9
4 4
```

Comment: Why are you using std::round() ? shouldn't discrete_dist return an integer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the std::uniform_real_distribution along with an interval table to do such a lookup.

What we can do is generate a number from 0.0 to 1.0 and map it into the integer space with a sort of lookup table.

For example:

```
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>

struct TableEntry
{
    double upper_bound = 0.0f;
    int value = 0;

    //for std::is_sorted, std::Upper_bound;
    bool operator<(TableEntry const& other) const
    {
        return this->upper_bound < other.upper_bound;
    }

};

struct Generator
{
    Generator():
        gen(std::random_device()()), //seed the random number generator
        dis(0.0, 1.0) //we want a value between - and 1
    {
        break_table.push_back({0.1, 0}); //10 percent probability of yielding 0
        break_table.push_back({0.17, 1}); // (0.17 - 0.1) == 7% chance of yielding 1

        //fill in the rest of the table uniformly

        double step = (1.0 - 0.17)/98; //98 values remaining, distribute equally

        for(int i = 2; i < 100; i++)
        {
            break_table.push_back({0.17 + (i-1)*step, i});
        }

        assert(std::is_sorted(begin(break_table), end(break_table)));
        assert(abs(break_table.back().upper_bound - 1.0) < 0.00001);
    }

    //call the object as a function to get a value
    int operator()()
    {
        double bval = dis(gen); //bval is in interval [0, 1);

        // std::upper_bound returns an iterator to the first value bigger than bval
        auto break_entry = std::upper_bound(begin(break_table), end(break_table), TableEntry{bval, 0});

        //special case: we're off the end of the scale
        if(break_entry == end(break_table)) return break_table.back().value;
        else return break_entry->value;
    };

private:

    std::vector<TableEntry> break_table;
    std::mt19937 gen;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dis;
};




int main()
{
    Generator g;

    //verify the probabilities
    const size_t N = 10'000'000;
    std::map<int, size_t> number_counts; // keep track of occurences of each number
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        int v = g();
        number_counts[v]++;
    }
    for(auto const& kv: number_counts)
    {
        double p = static_cast<double>(kv.second) / N;
        std::cout << kv.first << " : " << p * 100.0 << "%\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After running this code, I get the following distribution:

```
0 : 10.0069%
1 : 7.01544%
2 : 0.84899%
3 : 0.84358%
4 : 0.8462%
5 : 0.84468%
6 : 0.85324%
7 : 0.85023%
8 : 0.85003%
9 : 0.84862%
...
99 : 0.84219%
```

... which looks pretty good.